# How to disable JButton without changing background on Netbeans

Tags: java, jbutton, background-color

How can I disable a button without changing the colour of the background. When I press ready, the ready button and the blue button are disabled. But I want to keep the colour of the blue button.
Could you help me? [On the left the blue button, on the right the disabled buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SoHia.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easily: keep an instance variable 'isButtonEnabled', and instead of enabling or disabling the button, you change the value of this button.

Then, all you need to do:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
  if ( isButtonEnabled){
    // the actual code
  }
}
```

Comment: Button still depresses, user thinks it should do something

Comment: Either the appearance changes (enabled/disabled), or not. If you don't change the basic components, that doesn't really change. Unless you want to create your own UI component from scratch, which is pretty pointless, there's no immediate solution.

Comment: I don't get it. I need a button that chages the color of its background when pressed ( in that case blue) and disabled when the ready button is pressed.